# How to resolve Typescript errors in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

The error list in Visual Studio 2022 is showing 776 errors related to Typescript files that are completely unrelated to the current project. I try cleaning the solution but the errors are removed temporarily. These errors do not prevent me from running webpack or building the solution. The project is able to build successfully. Any ideas on how to remove these errors for the error list?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Upgraded to Visual Studio Community 17.3.4
using vb and typescript
100s of typescript errors as soon as I open a typescript file.
It seems the typescript syntax check only sees open files?
Go to definition only works if I open the file where the definition is.
Will need to download an earlier version to get on with my work.